# Encountered a problem when building my app with Appollo --> gem update xcodeproj?

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile, ipa

I would like to build an .ipa file for iOS 16. Therefore I tried to use Appollo. Based on th elogs below I tried already the following:

- I updated my gem data  with: gem update xcodeproj and gem update
- I changed at project.pbxproj the object version to 56 and compatibilityVersion to Xcode 14.0
  My assumption: This problem is not the problem of my project I think it is maybe an issue of the remote pc which tries to build my project.

Thank you all very much. Hope somebody can help me.

While building my application with [Appollo](https://appollo.space) I got the following error:
Here are my full logs:

```
Build started at 2023-05-13 08:07:53.715831+00:00
...
Deleting .flutter-plugins-dependencies... 0ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins... 0ms
The Flutter CLI developer tool uses Google Analytics to report usage and diagnostic data
along with package dependencies, and crash reporting to send basic crash reports.
This data is used to help improve the Dart platform, Flutter framework, and related tools.
Telemetry is not sent on the very first run.
To disable reporting of telemetry, run this terminal command:
flutter --disable-telemetry.
If you opt out of telemetry, an opt-out event will be sent,
and then no further information will be sent.
This data is collected in accordance with the
Google Privacy Policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy).
Resolving dependencies...
_flutterfire_internals 1.0.12 (1.3.0 available)
archive 3.3.1 (3.3.7 available)
args 2.3.1 (2.4.1 available)
background_locator_2 2.0.5 (2.0.6 available)
checked_yaml 2.0.2 (2.0.3 available)
cli_util 0.3.5 (0.4.0 available)
cloud_firestore 4.3.1 (4.7.0 available)
cloud_firestore_platform_interface 5.10.0 (5.14.0 available)
cloud_firestore_web 3.2.1 (3.5.0 available)
collection 1.17.1 (1.17.2 available)
cross_file 0.3.3+2 (0.3.3+4 available)
crypto 3.0.2 (3.0.3 available)
curved_navigation_bar 1.0.2 (1.0.3 available)
ffi 2.0.1 (2.0.2 available)
firebase_auth 4.1.1 (4.6.0 available)
firebase_auth_platform_interface 6.11.7 (6.15.0 available)
firebase_auth_web 5.2.2 (5.5.0 available)
firebase_core 2.4.1 (2.12.0 available)
firebase_core_platform_interface 4.5.2 (4.8.0 available)
firebase_core_web 2.1.0 (2.5.0 available)
firebase_crashlytics 3.0.10 (3.3.0 available)
firebase_crashlytics_platform_interface 3.3.10 (3.6.0 available)
firebase_database 10.0.9 (10.2.0 available)
firebase_database_platform_interface 0.2.2+17 (0.2.5 available)
firebase_database_web 0.2.1+19 (0.2.3 available)
firebase_messaging 14.0.4 (14.6.0 available)
firebase_messaging_platform_interface 4.2.5 (4.5.0 available)
firebase_messaging_web 3.2.5 (3.5.0 available)
firebase_storage 11.0.9 (11.2.0 available)
firebase_storage_platform_interface 4.1.25 (4.4.0 available)
firebase_storage_web 3.3.18 (3.6.0 available)
fixnum 1.0.1 (1.1.0 available)
flutter_foreground_task 3.10.0 (4.1.0 available)
flutter_launcher_icons 0.11.0 (0.13.1 available)
flutter_local_notifications 12.0.3 (14.0.0+2 available)
flutter_local_notifications_linux 2.0.0 (4.0.0+1 available)
flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface 6.0.0 (7.0.0+1 available)
flutter_map 3.1.0 (4.0.0 available)
flutter_map_marker_cluster 1.0.1 (1.1.0 available)
flutter_map_marker_popup 4.0.0 (4.1.0 available)
flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle 2.0.7 (2.0.14 available)
flutter_svg 1.1.6 (2.0.5 available)
geocoding 2.0.5 (2.1.0 available)
geocoding_platform_interface 2.0.1 (3.0.0 available)
geoflutterfire2 2.3.14 (2.3.15 available)
geolocator 8.2.1 (9.0.2 available)
geolocator_android 3.2.1 (4.1.7 available)
http 0.13.5 (0.13.6 available)
http_parser 4.0.1 (4.0.2 available)
image 3.2.2 (4.0.17 available)
image_picker 0.8.6 (0.8.7+5 available)
image_picker_android 0.8.5+4 (0.8.6+14 available)
image_picker_for_web 2.1.10 (2.1.12 available)
image_picker_ios 0.8.6+4 (0.8.7+4 available)
image_picker_platform_interface 2.6.2 (2.6.3 available)
intl 0.18.0 (0.18.1 available)
json_annotation 4.7.0 (4.8.1 available)
matcher 0.12.15 (0.12.16 available)
material_color_utilities 0.2.0 (0.5.0 available)
multi_select_flutter 4.1.2 (4.1.3 available)
path_provider_linux 2.1.7 (2.1.10 available)
path_provider_platform_interface 2.0.5 (2.0.6 available)
path_provider_windows 2.1.3 (2.1.6 available)
permission_handler 10.1.0 (10.2.0 available)
permission_handler_android 10.1.0 (10.2.0 available)
permission_handler_apple 9.0.6 (9.0.8 available)
permission_handler_windows 0.1.1 (0.1.2 available)
petitparser 5.0.0 (5.4.0 available)
plugin_platform_interface 2.1.3 (2.1.4 available)
shared_preferences 2.0.20 (2.1.1 available)
shared_preferences_android 2.0.14 (2.1.4 available)
shared_preferences_foundation 2.1.5 (2.2.2 available)
shared_preferences_linux 2.1.1 (2.2.0 available)
shared_preferences_platform_interface 2.1.0 (2.2.0 available)
shared_preferences_web 2.0.4 (2.1.0 available)
shared_preferences_windows 2.1.1 (2.2.0 available)
smooth_page_indicator 1.0.1 (1.1.0 available)
source_span 1.9.1 (1.10.0 available)
test_api 0.5.1 (0.5.2 available)
timezone 0.9.0 (0.9.2 available)
typed_data 1.3.1 (1.3.2 available)
url_launcher 6.1.10 (6.1.11 available)
url_launcher_android 6.0.26 (6.0.33 available)
url_launcher_linux 3.0.4 (3.0.5 available)
url_launcher_macos 3.0.4 (3.0.5 available)
url_launcher_windows 3.0.5 (3.0.6 available)
win32 3.0.1 (5.0.0 available)
xdg_directories 0.2.0+2 (1.0.0 available)
xml 6.1.0 (6.3.0 available)
yaml 3.1.1 (3.1.2 available)
Got dependencies!
----- Creating export.plist file -----
----- Modifying XCode config -----
----- Pod install -----
Analyzing dependencies
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `report'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/bin/pod:55:in `&lt;top (required)&gt;'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `&lt;main&gt;'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:284:in `raise_parser_error': [!] Dictionary missing value for key "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY", expected '=' and found "[" (Nanaimo::Reader::ParseError)
# -------------------------------------------
# CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = Runner/Runner.entitlements;
#
838&gt; CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "955a81efd147714167c646fd44b5c3cb8ea71abc";
^
# CODE_SIGN_STYLE = Automatic;
# -------------------------------------------
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:190:in `parse_dictionary'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:132:in `parse_object'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:193:in `parse_dictionary'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:132:in `parse_object'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:193:in `parse_dictionary'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:132:in `parse_object'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:193:in `parse_dictionary'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:132:in `parse_object'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:107:in `parse!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.22.0/lib/xcodeproj/plist.rb:27:in `read_from_path'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.22.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:211:in `initialize_from_file'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.22.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:113:in `open'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1194:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1188:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:107:in `analyze'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/bin/pod:55:in `&lt;top (required)&gt;'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `&lt;main&gt;'
Error updating sources. Exit code 1
Build stop order received at 2023-05-13 08:09:34.564146+00:00
```

[Appollo](https://appollo.space/)

UPDATE 15.05.2023:

Hello everybody,
I found out that when I enter appollo build and select configuration I can enter to the remote PC where I make my configurations. I changed the xcodeproject file and removed the "[sdk=iphoneos*]" in every --> CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "955a81efd147714167c646fd44b5c3cb8ea71abc";
as described in the log.

After that I entered flutter clean, flutter pub get and pod install and the building process worked!
Since my target is to create an ipa to be able to test my app on iOS16 I have to create a development build. When I try to enter the archive I get the following message: codesign wants to use the appolo keychain. At this message is a password required. I entreded every possible passwort, but I was not able to get access.

By trying to build direktly over the command appollo build start -development I get again the same issue like in the beginning. I deleted again the "[sdk=iphoneos*]" but it doesnt help. Somehow the building process add this automatically and I get again the same error as in the top.
I hope I was able to explain my current state.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

did you correctly apply the modifications on the configuration machine to your local code before sending it for the development build?
You can do that with the command appollo build patch then git apply appollo.patch.
Otherwise the changes you made on the configuration machine stay there and for the next build your untouched local code is sent.

Comment: Yes I tried, but it doesnt work. Always when I try to build it over appollo I get the same error with CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY. I removed now the CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY completly and it looks better. Now I get a different error: Error (Xcode): No signing certificate "iOS Development" found: No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team
ID "XXXXXXXX" with a private key was found